# Layout cannot be removed

Tags: android

I am trying to remove the layout when the apps starts.
I removed "setContentView" from the MainActivity.java file but still the layout is showing when the activty starts..

How can I remove the layout??

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
   setVisible(false); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Try after cleaning your project.post your code here.

Comment: No change after cleaning the project.

Comment: My code is public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }

}

Comment: Remove the layout... I've been out of the game for a few months but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to make a program that floats and when i click the button it goes back..now in my case the layout shows up and go back

Comment: What exactly you want to do using setVisible(false);

Comment: hide the layout from being showing up..

Comment: can you post the layout xml that your using ?

Comment: I am using RelativeLayout and no other element in it

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make much sense. By "layout", do you mean Activity? Do you mean you want an app without a UI? What do you mean by floats? What do you mean by "go back"?

Comment: Yep...i meant an app without a UI!

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your manifest, inside activity `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: It doesnt not stop the layout being popup but in makes the layout invisible